# Firebreath - passing parameter in callback function

Tags: javascript, firebreath

I have a code where from javascript i am passing a function

```
exportManager.RegisterCallbacks(function(progress) {
                                console.log("export prog " + progress);
                             }, function() {
                                console.log("Export Done");
                             }, function() {
                                console.log("Export Error");
                             }, function() {
                                console.log("Export Abort");
                             });
```

and in the plugin

```
m_currentExportProgress += progress;
int prog = (m_currentExportProgress.load() / m_totalProgress) * 100;

m_onProgress->InvokeAsync("", FB::variant_list_of(shared_from_this())(prog));
```

however when i write the result, i get

```
 export prog <JSAPI-Auto Javascript Object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is working exactly as it is set to do.  You are passing two parameters into the callback: first, a reference to your JSAPI instance `shared_from_this()` and second `prog`.

If you want to pass only one parameter, only provide one parameter:

```
m_onProgress->InvokeAsync("", FB::variant_list_of(prog));
```